# Good practices for packaging Python programs

Tags: python, deployment, packages, modules

I've been using Python for a while now, both in the context of personal and professional projects.

One thing that occured to me recently is that I had never thought about a good way to deploy Python programs. Basically, since it's mostly a bunch of scripts, I usually just copy them to the machine where I want it deployed and *voila* !

But I believe there should be some good practices as to how you should deploy Python projects. I've heard about Python Eggs but not familiar enough with it to see if it's a good choice. Or a plain old *tarball* with a bunch of Shell scripts to run the core module scripts?

Basically I'd like to be able to do a nice, elegant and self-contained deployment, and not just copying files here and there, as it doesn't allow version tracking easily and it's quite messy.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Python package tutorial](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io).  There are several ways described there: distutils and easyinstall are the main ones.  Note that some nix distributions will package things in their own format (.deb, rpm, etc) so you may look at those as well.